# Use array values as parameters

Tags: php

I'm trying to create an object and then call a method with custom parameters.

I can't use call_user_func_array because this doesn't create a new instance of the object, which I need later for calling $this in my classes.

```
$params = array('param1', 'param2', 'etc') ;
```

How can I do this so the result is equivelant to:

```
$controller = new $class ;
$controller->$method($param1, $param2, $etc) ;
```

I also don't want to use ReflectionClass as it is reported to be slower than instantiating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
$controller = new $class;
call_user_func_array(array($controller, $method), $params);
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: Thanks, I didn't I could use it like that :).

Comment: @Laz Karimov 9 minutes remain :)